# Dúvida com Random e Atividades Periódicas em GoLang

Tags: random, time, golang, timer

Existe alguma forma de eu fazer com que seja executado um `fmt.Printf(choosenCity)` a cada 6 horas e, que a cada execução, ele escolha um elemento diferente do Array?
Eu até consegui fazer com que ele executasse de forma periódica depois de algumas gambiarras, mas li que não é recomendado usar `time.sleep()` e ele sempre resulta no mesmo valor, a não ser que eu feche e execute o script novamente.

```
arrCities := [6]string{
    "Teste1",
    "Teste2",
    "Teste3",
    "Teste4",
    "Teste5",
    "Teste6",
}
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
choosenCity := arrCities[rand.Intn(len(arrCities))]
```

```
go func() {
        for true {
            fmt.Printf(choosenCity)
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        }
    }()
    // wait for 10 seconds before app finished
    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)

}

//OBS a Função `go func()` está dentro da main()
```

Eu gostaria de (sem fechar o script), a cada 6 horas, pickar um elemento aleatório da Array, e então imprimir.

Bom, todas as respostas me ajudaram de certa forma, achei que conseguiria exemplificar o problema com a syntax de código que eu passei acima. Mas na realidade, o que eu desejo ainda é um pouco diferente.

### **Para mais explicações:**

Na verdade este "gerador" de um número aleatório, é pra puxar um dado aleatório de uma API. Eu achei que com o exemplo que dei no post, conseguiria fazer, mas não consegui. Para explicar melhor, aqui vai um snippet do código como eu imaginei que funcionaria:

```
Choosen := fmt.Println(arrCities[r.Int64()]
URL := fmt.Sprintf("https://api.exemplo.io/data/?dado=%s", Choosen)
///... requisição e parsering da response
E então, aí, o "Ticker" que iria realizar tal atividade com a response da API.

///... requisição e parsering da response

//E AQUI VIRIA O TIMER 
fmt.Println(apiResults.Data1)
//
```

A questão é que preciso do Random pra API e com a resposta da API, aí sim, o Timer pra realiza

Comment: `fmt.Println` não vai funcionar, ao invés disso deixe só `arrCities[r.Int64()]`

Comment: Não entendi muito bem ainda, mas se quiser pegar um dado aleatório da API a cada 6h você pode colocar toda essa lógica dentro do timer

Comment: Eu quero que o gerador e o timer sejam separados, sacas? Não é um timer pra gerar um numero aleatório, é um timer pra executar uma função com a resposta de uma API que a requisição GET que vai pra api usa o número aleatório

Comment: Opa, agoar que vi o Println errado! hehehehe obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Veja se esse exemplo que eu fiz, pode ajudar.

https://play.golang.org/p/pVlOFcmCnhO

Deixei um Sleep apenas para o programa não executar infinitamente, mas voce pode usar algo como o `fmt.Scanln()` para aguardar até que alguma tecla seja pressionada ou simplesmente criar alguma regra que deixe o sistemas executando até algo acontecer.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você usa:

```
go func() {
        for true {
            fmt.Printf(choosenCity)
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        }
    }()
    // wait for 10 seconds before app finished
    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)

}
```

Você está apenas printando a string `choosenCity`. Ou seja, é igual à fazer: `var choosenCity = "algum coisa"` fora do loop. Por esse motivo: "ele sempre resulta no mesmo valor".

---

Você pode simplismente fazer:

```
go func() {
    for range time.Tick(1 * time.Second) {
            fmt.Println(arrCities[rand.Intn(len(cities))])
    }
}()
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "time"
)

var arrCities = []string{"Teste1", "Teste2", "Teste3", "Teste4", "Teste5", "Teste6"}

func main() {
    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(1 * time.Second) {
            l := big.NewInt(int64(len(arrCities)))
            if r, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, l); err == nil {
                fmt.Println(arrCities[r.Int64()])
            }
        }
    }()

    select {} // Impede o fechamento.
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/K2MV4HmQrHq

Comment: Muito bom, perfeito. Pequeno, local, versátil e funcional. Uma dúvida: caso eu quisesse que ao invés de imprimir com Println, ele apenas me retornasse o valor aleatório, como eu deveria fazer? Creio eu que não poderá ser realizada na go func(), provávlemente devo exportar pra uma função anterior a main() e depois chamá-la onde desejo usar a resposta, certo?